# Need to update range slider to 10 whenever user clicks

Tags: angularjs

I've range slider and I want to update it with `+10` or `-10`. I've jquery code and its working fine but i want to create it with angular js.

Here is example with jquery - 'http://jsfiddle.net/videma/HMNW5/2/'

and I've tried with angular js in this fiddle - 'http://jsfiddle.net/kB7d5/'

Comment: Tried using ui-slider component of angular?http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular you will of course need a custom directive. To make the component more re-usable, I implemented a directive with an isolate scope and the following attributes:

- min: The min value
- max: The max value
- step: The step for each click
- value: The initial value

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="range" id="rangeinput1" ng-model="range1"
        range-with-step min="0" max="200" step="20" value="100" />
```

In the directive, we need to request the `ngModel` directive in order to get hold of its **[controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)**, which gives us access to various useful properties and methods (**[`$modelValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24modelValue)**, **[`$setViewValue()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24setViewValue)**, **[`$parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#%24parsers)** etc).

Then, in the postLink function, we can set some default values (in case the user didn't specify some of the attributes), prevent the `mousemove` event (to prevent dragging the knob) and finally add a parser to process (and modify) the viewValue when it changes (and allow `step` by `step` changes only).

```
app.directive('rangeWithStep', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            min:   '@',
            max:   '@',
            step:  '@',
            value: '@',
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var min     = parseInt(scope.min)   || 0;
            var max     = parseInt(scope.max)   || 100;
            var step    = parseInt(scope.step)  || 10;
            scope.model = scope.value           || 
                          Math.ceil((max - min) / 2);

            elem.on('mousemove', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            });

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                var newViewValue  = parseInt(viewValue);
                var oldModelValue = parseInt(scope.model);

                if (newViewValue > oldModelValue) {
                    newViewValue = Math.min(max, oldModelValue + step);
                } else if (newViewValue < oldModelValue) {
                    newViewValue = Math.max(min, oldModelValue - step);
                }

                if (newViewValue !== viewValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$viewValue = newViewValue;
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return newViewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2qpva/)**.

Answer (score 0):

In angular the better way is using two way binding which simply updates your slider and values and string interpolation will display the updated range values:

```
<div id="slidecontainer" class="test">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value={{range}} class="slider" id="myRange" [(ngModel)]="rangeValues">
</div>
     <span class="value-span" id="plain_1">{{rangeValues}}</span>
</div>
```

And in component class you can deifine the range values:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 rangeValues : any = 3;
```